# Three finger swipe up gesture intermittenlty failing on Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: 22.04, touchegg

I have a Dell XPS 13 9360 and have recently installed Ubuntu 22.04

When I perform the three finger swipe up gesture while I am on a browser, it sometimes fails to show all open windows and just scrolls up the page of the browser.

I never had any issue with four finger right swipes using touchegg on Ubuntu 20.04. Is there any way I can change the three finger swipe to four finger swipe on Ubuntu 22.04?

Comment: Did you fix it?

Comment: @Muhammadsiddiq Yes, logout from Ubuntu and then click on the gear icon in the bottom right corner. Then choose "Ubuntu on Xorg" and log back in. Now none of your inbuilt gestures would work. Follow this link to install touchegg https://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2021/06/multi-touch-gestures-ubuntu-20-04/ It works better than Ubuntu 22.04's inbuilt gestures. You can then customize all your gestures using Touche to use 4 finger swipes. Also on "Ubuntu on Xorg" you won't have screen sharing issues on Zoom and Microsoft Teams.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution for this problem. I hope it helps others as well.

logout from Ubuntu and then click on the gear icon in the bottom right corner. Then choose "Ubuntu on Xorg" and log back in. Now none of your inbuilt gestures would work. Follow this link to install touchegg [ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2021/06/…](https://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2021/06/multi-touch-gestures-ubuntu-20-04/) It works better than Ubuntu 22.04's inbuilt gestures. You can then customize all your gestures using Touche to use 4 finger swipes. Also on "Ubuntu on Xorg" you won't have screen sharing issues on Zoom and Microsoft Teams

Answer (score 2):

same issue here, i'm using a acer sf314-59 with elan trackpad, i've notice that three finger swipe down will always be recognized, so if i want multitask view i put three fingers on trackpad, drag down a bit(this appears to be always recognized since my hidden dock always shows up, which happens when gnome is in this one-to one gesture session)and finally drag up to enter multitask view, i just moved from fedora35 to ubuntu 22.04, and fedora have no such issue at all

(i've also noticed that two finger scrolling upward sometimes isn't recognized either, and the cursor just moves as if i have only one finger on it, I wonder if you happens to have observed the same issue?)

Edit: I've downgraded libinput to 1.19.3, there is a significant difference in my case, now multifinger fail much less frequent, i'm currently running fedora 36

Comment: I have found the issue. If you align your three fingers perpendicularly to the screen and perform the swipe chances are that the gesture won't be recognized. However if you align your fingers horizontally toward the screen the gesture would be recognized almost every time. I hope they fix this bug sooner.

Comment: I've just switched to fedora 36 that runs gnome 42 and it also has the issue, hope they'll fix it soon

Answer (score 1):

Same issue here with x1 Carbon 5th gen. Most of the times I have to swipe up three fingers multiple times until it finally works

Comment: Finally someone else took notice too. I am still struggling with this issue and my hands are in pain. Someone had provided a fix for this by changing the three finger swipe to four finger swipe, when the first time I encountered this issue on Ubuntu 21.04 but I have lost the link to my that question and I don't know which stack exchange for Ubuntu I posted my question on.

Comment: Found the solution. Disable ubuntu desktop icons extension.

Comment: didn't work for me

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on solution from Behroz, if you logout, then choose user, before you enter your password, you should see a gear icon in the bottom right corner. And, sometimes there would be 'Ubuntu on wayland'. Choosing that, instead of the default 'Ubuntu' solved the issue for me.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).